# Why use variables for html attributes?

Tags: javascript, string, object

The site https://ipenburg.home.xs4all.nl/atkinsome/ provides the following code fragment:

```
    var IMG = new String('img');
    var DOT = new String('.');
    var CLASS = new STRING('class');
    DOT.concat(CLASS_FILTER)
```

why not simply write 'img' each time, or '.class'?

Comment: Looks like it might be some kind of misguided attempt at optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code quoted in your question looks like it was written by someone who isn't particularly proficient with JavaScript, since it unnecessarily creates `String` objects. If it exists at all, it should simply be:

```
var IMG = 'img';
var DOT = '.';
var CLASS = 'class';
```

or in ES2015+

```
const IMG = 'img';
const DOT = '.';
const CLASS = 'class';
```

As for the "why do this," the best justification I can come up with is that it allows you to find all of the places you've used `IMG` for the purposes of the `img` tag without also finding places you've used `'img'` for something else entirely.

What it *isn't* is future-proofing (or at least one hopes it's not meant to be). If you later changed `IMG` to be `'image'` without changing its name, that would be actively misleading subsequent authors working in the code.

Comment: Opinion: Using constants for magic numbers is reasonable and useful, but in general, using constants for literals doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Clear answer, thanks. Makes me more aware of copy catting pitfalls